# Cannot run "HelloWorld" on macintosh

Tags: java

On Macintosh OS 10.7.5, I'm able to successfully compile the following code:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void man(String [] args) {
        system.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

However, when i use the command "java HelloWorld," as my textbook instructs me to do, I am returned the following error: `"Could not find or load main class helloworld"`
So, What's going on here? Obviously, I'm absolutely brand new to java, and to programming in general.

Comment: what is your java file name? It should be HelloWorld.java and you have written main as man

Comment: Have you tried `HelloWorld` instead of `helloworld`?

Comment: not `man(String [] args)`, its `main(String [] args)` and not `system`, it `System`

Comment: How did you name the file ? what command you are running that you get this error ?

Comment: Are you compile the code, `javac filename.java`

Comment: @KamleshArya, it is helloworld.java, will the case matter in this case? and thanks, i've corrected it to main. @BitNinja, yes, i've tried it both ways. @alfasin, i named the original file "helloworld.java" and i'm running `javac users/.../helloworld.java` to compile, and `java HelloWorld` to run the program(per "The Java Programming Language, 4th Edition)

Comment: why down votes?... people who thinks that they never were noobs

Comment: I think you saved file with name helloworld. If so than your class name shoul be same

Comment: All down voters provide him solution for that. He started learning of java. Running first program is tuff for him as similar your tuffest task

Comment: So, I don't understand why this is considered off-topic? I'm having problems getting my code to compile. it can totally be replicated, like every time I compile. The issue, near as I can tell, was not caused by typos, and still exists. Please take this question off hold.

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code:

1. `public static void man` should be `public static void main`
2. `system.out.println` should be `System.out.println`

Suggestions:

```
Save your java program as HelloWorld.java
To Compile use: javac HelloWorld.java
To Run: java HelloWorld
```

Comment: thanks for the feeback. I've fixed the typos, and renamed the filename with appropriate caps, but i'm still getting this error. I'm wondering if i don't need to give a more specific file path? in my book, it simply said run `javac HelloWorld.java`, but i had to run `javac /users/.../HelloWorld.java` for it to compile. What could i use for a full pathname for `java HelloWorld`?

Comment: yup..a class file called bytecode will be generated at that location after compilation, so u need same full pathname while running as well

Comment: how can i find the full filename for the bytecode? will it be the same as the path for the .java file?

Comment: Go to that location javac /users/.../HelloWorld.java..you will find that there is a class file HelloWorld.class that is bytecode actually.Use java /users/.../HelloWorld to run your program

Comment: Ok, so i've run it with the full filename, and i get this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class .users.rasellers0.Desktop.java.HelloWorld.class` What does this mean? By the way, thanks for walking me through this, I know it must seem ridiculous that i can't even figure out the basics like this.

Comment: what command you use to run and compile?

Comment: I use the `javac /users/.../HelloWorld.java` command to compile, and the `java /users/.../HelloWorld.class` to run the program. This is per "The Java Programming Language, 4th Edition," by Ken Arnold.

Comment: remove .class while running.we dont have to refer that class.java will automatically do that..use java /users/.../HelloWorld to run the program

Comment: I've removed the .class, and am still getting the same error.

Comment: grr...I said to remove .class that you were putting at the end while running command not from system..Just Compile it using javac /users/.../HelloWorld.java after that a .class file will be generated at that location..dont delete that file.its bytecode..now run your program java /users/.../HelloWorld

Comment: I never deleted the .class file, sorry. Can you clarify what you mean by "not from system"?

Comment: you dont have enough reputation to be in chat for better explanation.Do one thing compile the program first use javac /users/.../HelloWorld.java and check any error at command prompt is there or not..if no error then check that location..whether there is .class file created or not

Comment: So there's no errors when I compile, and there is a .class file in the same directory as the original .java file.

Comment: yup...now run java /users/.../HelloWorld